# Convert a flat list into tree structure having the depth of each node

Tags: java, recursion, nested-loops

I'm using java and I have the need to convert a flat `Set<Object>` into a Set of Object which can contains others list of objects recursively.

I receive this JSON data from the react front-end:

```
[
    {
        name : "A",
        depth: "0",
        fullpath: "/A",
        subRows: null
    },
    {
        name : "B",
        depth: "0.0",
        fullPath: "/A/B"
        subRows: null
    },
    {
        name : "C",
        depth: "0.0.0",
        fullPath: "/A/B/C",
        subRows: null
    },
    {
        name : "D",
        depth: "1,
        fullPath: "/D",
        subRows: null
    }
]
```

and I would like to convert it to this structure (same data but with parent-child relationship):

```
[
    {
        name : "A",
        depth: "0",
        fullPath: "/A",
        subRows: [
            {
                name : "B",
                depth: "0.0",
                fullPath: "/A/B",
                subRows: [
                    {
                        name : "C",
                        depth: "0.0.0",
                        fullPath: "/A/B/C",
                        subRows: null
                    }
                ]
            }           
        ]
    }
    {
        name : "D",
        depth: "1,
        fullPath: "/D",
        subRows: null;
    }   
]
```

The most important field in the object is the **subRows** array which define the structure, all the others fields are just for the developer to understand the depth and the structure of the nodes (E.g. Depth contains the index of every parents' node plus the index of the current node, all separated with dots).

Please don't rely too much on the fullPath because objects' names are not unique.

Each of those objects is a Row object, in the front-end all the rows create a table. Following Row.java model class:

```
public class Row {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;


    private String name;
    private String depth;
    private String fullPath;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_PARENT")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Row parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy(clause = "id")
    private Set<Row> subRows = new LinkedHashSet<Row>();
    
    public Row(){}
    
    //Getter and Setter
}
```

Does anyone have ideas on how to do it? I've been hitting my head against it for few days.

Comment: Should't the depth for C be 0.0.0 iso 0.1.0? 0.1.0 seems to place it at the same level of B

Comment: You'are right, I 'll correct it , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the sudo code to perform the above task. You may have to handle some corner cases. But main idea is to maintain a list of `pendingRows`. For each row in this list, if the parent node is already present in `depthToRows` map, we will insert that row into the parents' subRows and remove the row from `pendingRows`. We need to repeat this until `pendingRows` is empty.

```java
        List<Row> inRows; //input to the algo
        List<Row> pendingRows = new LinkedList<>();
        Map<String, Row> depthToRows = new HashMap<>();

        pendingRows.addAll(inRows);
        while (!pendingRows.isEmpty()){
            for(Row row: inRows){
                depthToRows.put(row.getDepth(), row);
                //find the parent depth object
                String[] arr = row.getDepth().split(".");
                if(arr.length > 1){
                    String parentDepth = String.join(".", Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, arr.length - 1));
                    if(null != depthToRows.get(parentDepth)){
                        depthToRows.get(parentDepth).getSubRows().add(row);
                        pendingRows.remove(row);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: amazing logic ! Many thanks you really saved me !